# object variable or with block variable not set vba excel while trying to do vlookup

Tags: vba, excel, range, vlookup

I am trying to perform vlookup from one sheet to another in same workbook. But getting the run-time error "*object variable or with block variable not set*". If anyone can have a look and help me out here. Kind of stuck here from few days

Also I am unable to print values in immediate block for the particular range for debugging

```
Dim c1 As Range  
Dim Values1 As Range  
Dim Values2 As Range  

Values1 = Sheet2.Range("A2:A14")  'Getting the error here
Values2 = Sheet1.Range("A2:C14")  

AC_Row = Sheet2.Range("H1").Row  
AC_Col = Sheet2.Range("H1").Column

For Each c1 In Values1  
Debug.Print c1.Value  'Is this correct way to print??
Sheet2.Cells(AC_Row, AC_Col) = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(c1, Values2, 2, True)  
 AC_Row = AC_Row + 1  
Next c1
```

Comment: you seem not to have any `Sheet2` sheet: use `Values1 = Worksheets("mySheetName").Range("A2:A14")` and change `mySheetName` to your actual sheet name. The same with `Values2`

Comment: @DisplayName I also thought so and upvoted your comment only to find that Excel raises different error message if `Sheet2` doesn't exist. Excel raises `424: Object Required`.

Answer (score 4):

Please use `Set` keyword to set `Range` object like below:

```
Set Values1 = Sheet2.Range("A2:A14")  
Set Values2 = Sheet1.Range("A2:C14")
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank You folks, I was able to achieve the desired result. Please find below my code.

```
 Dim rng As Range
 Dim rng1 As Range
 Dim c1 As Range
 Dim datavalue_Target As Variant
 Dim datavalue_OuterB As Variant

    Dim x As Integer
    Dim y As Integer

    x = 2
    y = 2

    Lastrow_A = Sheets("Sheet2").Cells(Sheets("Sheet2").Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    Set rng = Application.Range("Sheet2!A2:A" & Lastrow_A)
    Lastrow_C = Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(Sheets("Sheet1").Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp).Row
    Set rng1 = Application.Range("Sheet1!A2:C" & Lastrow_C)
    'Debug.Print Sheet2.Cells(1, 2).Value

    For Each c1 In rng.Cells
        'Debug.Print c1.Value
        On Error Resume Next
        datavalue_Target = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(c1, rng1.Cells, 2, False)
        If Err = 0 Then
        Sheets("Sheet2").Range("H" & x).Value = datavalue_Target
        End If
        On Error GoTo 0

        x = x + 1
    Next c1

    For Each c1 In rng.Cells
        'Debug.Print c1.Value
        On Error Resume Next
        datavalue_OuterB = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(c1, rng1.Cells, 3, False)
        If Err = 0 Then
        Sheets("Sheet2").Range("I" & y).Value = datavalue_OuterB
        End If
        On Error GoTo 0

        y= y + 1
    Next c1
```